# str_repeat and negative numbers

Tags: php

I know str_repeat cannot handle negative numbers; and I actually did have a work around for the problem i've got right now, however the work around only worked on my test server... anyway the problem i'm having is with the health display system for my website. I have it so if a user's health goes below 0 it says "Hospitalized" and if its above 0 it shows a couple hearts.
but the code mysteriously stopped working and now just gives me this error: 
Warning: str_repeat(): Second argument has to be greater than or equal to 0 in /home5/thehave8/public_html/gmz1023/includes/class/template_engine.php on line 53

which i'm taking to mean that the number is negative.

```
        $vitals = parent::userVitals($uid);
    $hearts = round($vitals['health']/15);
    if($hearts <= 0)
    {
        $health = 'hospitalized';
    }
    if($hearts >= 10)
    {
        $health = str_repeat('&hearts;', 13);
        $health .= '+';
    }
    if($hearts < 10)
    {
        $health = str_repeat('&hearts;', $hearts);
    }
    return $health;
```

Comment: Try `else if` instead of `if` for the second and third checks.

Answer (score 1):

Use elseif. Your code is currently executing both the first and the third if-statement when `$hearts` is less or equal to zero. With elseif, the third if-statement will not be executing if the first one matches. See [the docs for elseif](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php).

```
$hearts = round($vitals['health']/15);
if($hearts <= 0)
{
    $health = 'hospitalized';
}
elseif($hearts >= 10)
{
    $health = str_repeat('&hearts;', 13);
    $health .= '+';
}
elseif($hearts < 10)
{
    //Now this is actually more than 0 and less than 10
    //You could even use else here
    $health = str_repeat('&hearts;', $hearts);
}
return $health;
```

Comment: This did it. Thank you! I think i orginally had it as an elseif statement but set the code back to an earlier state. which dun goofed things up.

Answer (score 0):

You're checking for `$hearts <= 0`, and then dropping through to a check for `$hearts <10`, which is also true - that's where your error is.

Try this:

```
if(($hearts < 10) && ($hearts >0))
{
    $health = str_repeat('&hearts;', $hearts);
}
```